# How do I generate the following series of numbers in Python using List Comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to learn List Comprehension, given two numbers as input, I want to generate a series of consecutive numbers.

For example:

```
Input:  11,16 
Output: [(11,12),(11,12,13),(11,12,13,14),(11,12,13,14,15),(11,12,13,14,15,16)]
```

So I am trying something like the following:

```
def genSeries(start,stop):
    return [(start, x) for y in range(start,stop) for x in ?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (wow so many people typing simultaneously :-) I suggest simply add 2 once ...:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

def gen_series(start, stop):
    return [tuple(range(start, x + 2)) for x in range(start, stop)]

print(gen_series(11, 16))
```

yields:

```
[(11, 12), (11, 12, 13), (11, 12, 13, 14), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)]
```

**Update**: Here is a generator function, so in python v3 one has lazy evaluation ... in python v2 the range might need replacement by xrange to achieve full leisure ;-)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function


def series_gen(start, stop):
    """Generator function solution, where the caller can call list on."""
    for x in range(start, stop):
        yield tuple(range(start, x + 2))


print(list(series_gen(11, 16)))
```

yields (surprise, surprise):

```
[(11, 12), (11, 12, 13), (11, 12, 13, 14), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)]
```

Also as @MartijnPieters kindly notes: One could also just write for the function:

```
def gen_series(start, stop):
    return ((range(start, x + 2)) for x in range(start, stop))
```

But take care about the outer parenthesis "being" a generator expression, the "inner" being short for a tuple (trusting it will receive more than one entry.

Comment: This adds 2 for each `x` however, as that expression is re-executed for each iteration over `range(start, stop)` ;-) You can easily limit this to adding `2` only twice..

Comment: Your generator function works fine in Python 2 as well, and is just as lazy there. You could just have replaced the square brackets from the list comprehension with `(..)` parentheses to cerate a *generator expression*, with the exact same effect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, good you note it. Thanks. I still tend to offer more explicit yield to "strangers", as the sneaky parentheses are quite overbooked, and the yield is clear (and OK in a "spacy" function like setting), as a generator expression itself of course, I would use `(...)` ... in python v2 the range though ... I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
[tuple(range(start, i+1)) for i in range(start+1, stop+1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an loop over the `stop` value; that way you can produces a *series* of ranges, from `range(11, 13)` through to `range(11, 17)`:

```
def genSeries(start, stop):
    return [tuple(range(start, endvalue)) for endvalue in range(start + 2, stop + 2)]
```

Note that the end value is not included in a `range()`, so to produce the values from `11` through to `16` inclusive, you need to tell `range()` to use `17` as the end value. This is also why the `endvalue` range loops from `start + 2` through to `stop + 2`; the first range is produced from `11` to `12` inclusive, so you need to start at `start + 2` to get the exclusive stop value, and the last range goes from `start` to `stop` inclusive, so you need to use `range(start, stop + 1)` to produce that, and that in turn means the `endvalue` range must go to `stop + 2`.

Just convert the `range()` object for each separate `endvalue` directly to a tuple.

Demo:

```
>>> genSeries(11, 16)
[(11, 12), (11, 12, 13), (11, 12, 13, 14), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)]
```